# How to access widgets in different tabs of QTabWidget?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, widget, qt4

I know how to create a new tab and add new widgets to a new tab of QTabWidget.

My Code:

```
QPlainTextEdit *plainTextEdit = new QPlainTextEdit;
ui->tabWidget->addTab(plainTextEdit , "New");
```

When I clicked the button, new tab and its own QPlainTextEdit widget will be created.

But I don't know how to set property to different QPlainTextEdit or save their contents.

For example, I want set font size of QPlainTextEdit in tab4 and save contents of QPlainTextEdit in tab5.

How to achieve these functions?

Answer (score 1):

To get the widget at a tab index you can use the `widget` function of `QTabWidget` .

In your case in which `QPlainTextEdit` is the only widget of every tab page :

```
QPlainTextEdit* plainTextEdit = (QPlainTextEdit*) ui->tabWidget->widget(0); // for the first tab

plainTextEdit->setPlainText("Hello!");
```

If the `QPlainTextEdit` is not the only widget, you need to get the `children` of the widget and find the `QPlainTextEdit` in them :

```
QList<QPlainTextEdit *> allTextEdits = ui->tabWidget->widget(0)->findChildren<QPlainTextEdit *>();
if (allTextEdits.count() >0) 
    allTextEdits[0]->setPlainText("Hello!");;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have pointers to your `QPlainTextEdit`s as members of the main widget class:

```
class Widget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Widget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Widget();

    void someFunction();
private:
    QPlainTextEdit *plainTextEdit;
}

Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
   ...
   plainTextEdit = new QPlainTextEdit;
   ui->tabWidget->addTab(plainTextEdit , "New");
}

void Widget::someFunction()
{
   plainTextEdit->setPlainText("Hello!");
}
```